# Можно сказать "службу стоять"?

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

*Вот эта большая семья... тут своих и вымолила. О том родители не забывают – хоть раз в месяц, но непременно в монастыре **службы стоят**.*

***Стоять службу*** – это допустимое выражение или авторский вариант?

И попутный вопрос. Как лучше: ***обязательно*** или ***непременно***? Есть между словами смысловая и стилистическая разница?

Comment: Мне "непременно" нравится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из толкового словаря Кузнецова:
[СТОЯ́ТЬ](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Stojat-50613.html)
2. Выполнять какую-либо работу, заниматься каким-либо делом, связанным с пребыванием в таком положении. *Стоять у станка. Стоять на посту. Стоять в карауле, на дежурстве, на часах. Стоять часовым, караульным, дневальным. Стоять за мольбертом, за кульманом, у пульта управления. Стоять вахту, на вахте. **Стоять обедню, заутреню*** (присутствовать на церковной службе во время обедни, заутрени).

*Старая церковь, особенно во время православных праздников, была переполнена, люди вынуждены были **стоять службу** под открытым небом и в снег, и в дождь* ([из статьи](https://stroi.mos.ru/articles/novyi-khram-srietienskogho-monastyria-bim-tiekhnologhii-skrytyie-inzhieniernyie-sieti-i-3d-meppingh)).

Я бы написала так (раз в месяц — один раз стоят):
*...хоть раз в месяц, но непременно в монастыре **службу стоят.***
И непременно оставила бы наречие "непременно" — оно "помягче".
"Обязательно" — больше смахивает на "в обязательном порядке", а тут этого нет. Здесь — не по обязанности, а с душевным теплом и с бесконечной благодарностью.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма.

Comment: И Вам поклон — за оценку и возможность в очередной раз пораскинуть мозгами.

Answer (score 1):

"Непременно" мне нравится. Не стал бы менять на "обязательно".

*"Стоять службу"* не слышал чтобы говорили, говорят обычно *"**от**стоять службу".* [Вот](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%83) примеры.

Действительно, в Нацкорпусе есть "стоял/стояли службу", но кроме примера 1930 года Алексея Толстого, все остальные самое раннее 1999 года.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. В Нацкорпусе есть примеры с сочетанием "стоять службу", даже в новых книгах (2015, 2012), но я не могу понять, насколько оно нормативное.  На слух оно  кажется странным. Что касается "непременно", то я не планирую его менять, просто интересно, чем они отличаются. Считается, что нет одинаковых синонимов. Как вы думаете, чем?

Comment: Римма уже написала: не по обязанности, а по собственному горячему желанию (непременно).

Answer (score 1):

Авторский вариант, где изменено стандартное употребление:
*Выстоять всю службу.* || Выдержать.

*Отстоять всю службу.* || Как-то ощущается коннотация "*отработать, раз требуется*". Этот вариант меньше нравится.

Если стоять, то на службе.

Слова разные, хотя довольно похожие. "*Непременно*" лучше и звучит интереснее.
В "*обязательно*" есть коннотация обязанности перед кем-то или следуя какому-то принципу.
В случае с "*непременно*" подходит словарное значение "*неизменно характерно для чего-то*".